# Listview adds items twice

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to add single row to my ListView. When I run the code below, there are 2 lines added, one with the text I want to add, and an empty one. Why is the empty one added? (lines[0] is a file with (*for now*) 1 line in it)

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listviewrow, R.id.txt_listviewItem, lines){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View myView = convertView;

        if (myView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            myView = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewrow, null);
        } else {
            TextView txt_listviewItem = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.txt_listviewItem);
            txt_listviewItem.setText(lines[0]);

        }
        return myView;
    };

... 

listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

When I debug, listview.setAdapter(listAdapter) is called **before AND after** the getView code runs. Why? I only call it once.

Comment: What is the content of `lines`?

Comment: And your debugger will hit the setAdapter line, at which point getView is called for every object in the adapter, and it returns back to setAdapter... The setAdapter doesn't run twice

Comment: Please add more of your code - your problem is elsewhere, not in the code you posted.

Comment: `lines` is an array with all the lines from a file (I want only the first line `line[0]` added to my listView

Answer (score 1):

you have use Viewholder to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but does your text file include a "new line" character on the second row? Or, should I say, does your text file have, indeed, one line or two lines out of which the second is just a \n character?

Comment: Apparently, yes. But why does that matter? I only use `lines[0] `, so It should only use one line I think

Comment: It is taking the one line that you have coded for but I think that one line includes the new line character. It could be that the end of first line was considered only on the new line (the line with \n character) rather than the first line itself. Not sure if that's the case. Just a guess.

Comment: @wilemjan92 you mentioned "lines[0] is a file with (for now) 1 line in it". That's different from what you are saying now :).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.listviewrow, R.id.txt_listviewItem, lines){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View myView = convertView;

            if(myView==null){
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                myView = li.inflate(R.layout.listviewrow, null);
                TextView txt_listviewItem = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.txt_listviewItem);
                txt_listviewItem.setText(lines[0]);

            }
            return myView;
        };
 listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```